# Do astronomers measure radio waves absorption to know the shape of a celestial body?

Tags: planet, radio-astronomy, photons

I do not have much knowledge about radio astronomy. I know that astronomers know an objects' shape by measuring the reflected photons that reach radiotelescopes, but can they measure also the absorbed ones for the same purpose?

Comment: You have asked lots of similar questions on Physics SE. What is it about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_astronomy (that you have been referred to) that is unclear?

Comment: Also, could you clarify the question? Is this about radar, or about seeing a [radio shadow](http://www.astro.yale.edu/~lds4/Research_files/droppedImage.jpg) due to the [SZ effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunyaev%E2%80%93Zel%27dovich_effect)? Note: The wikipedia explanation is somewhat lacking in this context.

Comment: This seems very unclear. My first thought was "If the photon is absorbed, then it can't be measured"... but that seems too obvious. Please clarify.